# How to calculate mean relative error on test datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

```
def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(40002, 12)))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences= True))
    model.add(LSTM(50, return_sequences= True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(30))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))

    def rmse(Y_test, prediction):
        return K.sqrt(K.mean(K.square(Y_test-prediction)))

    # compile 
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=rmse, metrics=['mean_squared_error', rmse])

    return model

# fit the model
model = create_model()

model.fit(x_train, Y_train, shuffle=False, verbose=1, epochs=10)
  
# # predict model
prediction = model.predict(x_test, verbose=0)
print(prediction)
```

How to calculate mean relative error for tensor inputs i.e my Y_test and prediction are tensor.
Y_test and prediction as 2 values

Example:

```
Y_test = [[0.2,0.003],
          [0.3, 0.008]]


prediction = [[0.4,0.005],
              [0.5,0.007]]

mean_relative_error = mean(absolute(0.2-0.4)/0.2 + absolute(0.003-0.005)/0.003), mean(absolute(0.3-0.5)/0.3 + absolute(0.008-0.007)/0.008)

mean_relative_error = [0.533, 0.3925]
```

Please note that I don't want to use it for backpropagation to improve the network.

Comment: if your doubt is solved and your answer is not answered then please add your found answer for the community.

Answer (score 2):

Would have added like this:

```
from tensorflow.math import reduce_mean, abs, reduce_sum

relative_error = reduce_mean(reduce_sum(abs(prediction-Y_test)/prediction, axis=1))
# [0.9, 0.54285717]

mean_relative_error = reduce_mean(relative_error)
# 0.7214286
```

I couldn't use `tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)` because of a bug. The `MeanAbsoluteError` still does reduce to mean despite specifying it not to. The bug reported [HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27190)

Comment: Question is tagged with `tensorflow` and is using `tensorflow` and not `pytorch`

Comment: Ops! my bad....

Comment: @rafathasan
Thank you, I guess here this will take the mean of all the values i.e from 1st row to last row and return the result. But I need mean of 2 values in output as I have mentioned in the question.  Please see I have multiple output in Y_test and prediction, please see in question, I have added Y_test and prediction values.

Comment: @sp05 Can give an example how `prediction` actually looks like?

Comment: @rafathasan I have added it in the question

Comment: I have looked at it but it is making more confusion due to wrong syntax.

Comment: @rafathasan, is it better now?
prediction = [0.4,0.005] , [0.5,0.007]

Comment: you require `mean_relative_error` for each element i.e. in matrix instead of single mean value? You can use `axis` parameter to specify the axis in [reduce_mean](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_mean). If I got your doubt properly.

Comment: Check it now I have edited and ad `reduce_sum` . @sp05

Comment: @GodWin, adding axis solved the problem